# Renting a property for more than one year

Tags: legal-terms, rental-property, rent, washington

I read the following sentence on a website regarding rental properties in Washington:

> In Washington State, if your lease is longer than 1 year a Legal Description of the property is required  along with a notarized lease agreement.

What does "a legal description of the property is required" mean?

Answer (score 2):

[That statement](https://tsquareproperties.net/snohomish-county-rental-agreement/) goes beyond what Washington law actually says.
[RCW 59.18.210](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=59.18&full=true#59.18.210) states (for residential tenancies) that

> Tenancies from year to year are hereby abolished except when the same
> are created by express written contract. Leases may be in writing or
> print, or partly in writing and partly in print, and shall be legal
> and valid for any term or period not exceeding one year, without
> acknowledgment, witnesses or seals

In Washington, a supposedly multi-year lease which is not notarized is converted into a month-to-month lease. This is in distinction to mobile home lot leases ([RCW 59.20.050](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=59.20&full=true#59.20.050)) which allow terms of more than one year. There is no requirement to attach a legal description of the property, which would be meaningless for an apartment built on a particular land parcel (hundreds of rental units may exist on a parcel with a specific legal description).

A detailed analysis of a "legal description" that is to be included in records of survey for land surveyor is set forth [here](https://www.atg.wa.gov/ago-opinions/legal-description-required-records-survey) by the AG, given [RCW 58.09.060](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=58.09&full=true#58.09.060), who notes that it is not defined under the law, and instead

> we conclude that the "legal description" required by the statute is
> simply that description of a tract of real property which is
> sufficient to meet the requirements of a valid deed of conveyance
> under the long-standing provisions of RCW 64.04.010; i.e.,". . . a
> description of land sufficiently definite to locate it without
> recourse to oral testimony, . . ."

citing various kinds of technical measurements that could be used to record the boundaries of real property.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "a legal description of the property is required" mean?

It means a set of specs of the property. The examples from the following Washington court opinions will give you an idea about what a legal description of a property entails:

[*Harris v. Ski Park Farms*, 120 Wn.2d 727, 731 (1993)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1993847120wn2d7271811)

[*Lloyd v. Montecucco*, 924 P.2d 927, 929 (1996)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19961851924p2d92711834)

[*Beriault v. King*, (Feb. 2009)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inwaco20090209733)

[*Popelier v. Samse*, (Oct. 2015)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inwaco20151021c75)

[*In the matter of Estate of Hall*, (Mar. 2019)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inwaco20190312f29)

Just look for keyword "*legal description*" in those court opinions.